# Question regarding checking the state of a checkbox class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, checkbox

I'll try and make this question simple. Can I assign a class to a series of different checkboxes, and use Jquery to do something when any one of those checkboxes is checked? Searching around on the internet I have found documentation on grabbing the name: `$('input[name=foo]').is(':checked')` but when I swap out the name attribute for the class attr, it won't work! How can I set an event to occur if any of the checkboxes with this certain class is checked? Please help me out! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to test whether or not a particular element has been assigned a certain class e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=something]:checkbox").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).hasClass("foo")) {
           // the checkbox has been checked and has a class of foo
        }
    });
});
```

[Try a demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tRb5m/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the status of all the checkbox at a single go by putting same name to all the checkboxes.